# Como solucionar: Error while installing dependencies cuando intento crear una base de datos con Strapi?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, strapi

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos con Strapi, la idea es usar PostgreSQL. Quiero crear el proyecto elijiendo Custom y configurandolo por mi mismo, eligiendo nombre, lenguajes, etc. Pero una vez que ya agregué nombre, password y todo lo que me pide de la base de datos me salta este error
"Error while installing dependencies:". No se a que se debe. Tiene solución? Estoy usando node 18 y tengo windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución solo hay que instalar esbuild mediante

```
npm install esbuild@0.16.17
```

y después crear el proyecto.